# C++ makefile - linker not find external lib

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile that successfully build *.obj files. After I reach the linking part, I have a lot of error to `undefined reference`.

```
CC = g++

INCLUDE_DIRS = -I/usr/include/freetype2/ -I../MyLibs/ \
               -I../MyLibs/svg/

LIB_DIRS = -L./ -L../MyLibs/ -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/lib64/mysql/

LIBS = -lMyUtils -lfreetype  -lmysqlclient -lsqlite3 


CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -lm -lpthread -lstdc++ -ldl  -Wall -O2 \
         $(INCLUDE_DIRS)

OBJ = *** list of obj files ***

BIN = my_program

$(BIN): $(OBJ) $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@
```

I am unable to see what can be wrong. MyUtils is static library, that I have also build using different makefile (If I look inside with `ar`, I see all obj present). Also, I have used the same library to build another project (dynamic library) and build was correctly finished.

A am using gcc 4.7.2 under CentOS 6.5.

Comment: For me `$(CFLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS)` when first and third variables contain `-l` option but second variable contains `-L` looks suspicious. Can you try `$(LIB_DIRS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)` ?

Comment: @Gluttton I have moved all -l together and all -L as well, but problem persist

Comment: Strange to list `$(OBJS)` twice on the dependency list for `$(BIN)`.  I don't know if this would cause compile problems, but it would probably cause link problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linker recipe places the libraries before the object files that require them. The linker
will only examine a library to resolve undefined references it already noted in previously linked objects,
so if you place all the libraries before all the object files then none of libraries are
examined and all of the calls to those libraries in the object files end up undefined.

Rewrite e.g as:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LIB_DIRS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

(And no need to duplicate the $(OBJ) prerequisities)

Comment: Even simpler: copy the default link rule from `make -f /dev/null --print-data-base`, namely `$(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@` (and put your `$(LIB_DIRS)` into the standard `$(LDFLAGS)`).